# libreoffice writer figure cross-refencence

Tags: images, libreoffice-writer, cross-reference, caption

In LibreOffice Writer I cannot create a cross-reference to an image, it is only possible to create cross-reference to it's caption. By using the created link in PDF the screen jumps to the caption, not to the image.

Comment: Did you try to insert a bookmark above the image and point the crossref to that bookmark?

Comment: hmm, not, because that could be very exhausting in the case of more than 100 images

Comment: OK - maybe using hyperlinks will fit your needs. See my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions - depending on your needs:

1. For single images, you could **insert a bookmark above the image, and add a cross-reference pointing to that bookmark**. In the resulting PDF, the crossref jumps to the image. Of course, this isn't viable if there are a lot of pics to cross-ref (you may use a macro for this kind of task).
2. **Instead of cross references, use [hyperlinks](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Working_with_hyperlinks)**. While cross references can't address objects like images directly and need a caption as target, hyperlinks may point to images directly.

   - Pro: no need to put additional bookmarks near your images.
   - Con: You can't automatically use the target page number or caption as hyperlink text.

To insert a hyperlink to an image: Make sure to select "`Document`" at the left of the insert Hyperlink dialogue (1), then click the button at the right of the "`Target`" text field (2). A list of target categories appears, allowing to select the appropriate image:

[image: Insert Hyperlink]

Comment: hmm, thank you so much, the solution with macro sounds good, because I have some programming skills. Do you have any example like this in macro?

Comment: Sorry, no, i don't have an example. But [Andrew Pitonyaks's page](http://www.pitonyak.org/) is a great starting point regarding OOo macros.